# update order status on WHMCS

Tags: php, whmcs

I'm developing a payment gateway on the WHMCS system. My question is I want to update the order status on the WHMCS system after the transaction is done.
I want to know if there is any global variable or method or API I can call to update the order status from my plugin(my side)?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is an internal API or external

https://developers.whmcs.com/api-reference/acceptorder/